# Alfresco lucene query with PARENT search all children recursively?

Tags: lucene, parent, alfresco

I'm doing a lucene search using PARENT. But returns me 0 results, and it's not ok. My query is like this:

```
TYPE:"{mymodel}exp" AND PARENT:"workspace://SpacesStore/30da316f-9d2a-4e37-a28b-89d86bff6582" AND =@myexp\:num_exp:"Exp 433"
```

The problem is that the node I'm searching isn't direct children of parent node.

PARENT don't search recursively? Are there another way to search on children and subchildren? I can't use PATH, because I need a quick response and I read that PATH isn't optimal.

Comment: Did you try actually benchmarking it with PATH?

Comment: If you use SOLR and one of the later versions then PATH is oke to use. They increased the performance quite a bit.

Comment: I use Alfresco 4.1.6 and SOLR 1.4. With this versions I read PATH isn't advisable. But my question is about PARENT. Don't search recursively? Are there something equivalent to search childrens and subchildrens?

Comment: Also, the PARENT tag is not working in combination with TAG or cm:name for partial search. For example: PARENT:"53710803-ea2a-48c1-9a1a-18bee7c4c5a4" AND TAG:"xyz" is not bringing results, but it's working fine with just TAG:"xyz". Do let me know if somebody faced this or there is a solution to it.

Answer (score 4):

Indeed, PARENT is **not** searching recursively. This what PATH is intended for: to search recursively.

And this is also why PATH is slower than PARENT: it is slower *because* it searches recursively.